# C++: track access to array element

Tags: c++, arrays, trace

I have a class that I use to keep track of the values assumed by a variable. I implemented it by overloading operator=.
Usage example:

```
myType var0;
var0 = 1;
var0 = 3;
```

generates on stdout:

```
1
3
```

This works fine with variables, but not with arrays. How can I extend this feature?

Comment: It should work exactly the same for **array elements**.  Could you post your MWE?

Comment: What about the subscript operator, operator[] ?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be overloading the `[]` operator to return a "proxy" - an object that references your variable, and overloads the `=` operator to do the tracking.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct myArray;

class proxy {
    myArray &array;
    int index;
public:
    proxy(myArray &_array, int _index)
    :   array(_array)
    ,   index(_index) {
    }
    proxy& operator=(int value);
    operator int() const;
};
struct myArray {
    int data[100];
    proxy operator[](int index) {
        return proxy(*this, index);
    }
};

proxy& proxy::operator=(int value) {
    cout << "Asigning " << value << " to element " << index << endl;
    array.data[index] = value;
    return *this;
}

proxy::operator int() const {
    cout << "Reading element at " << index << endl;
    array.data[index];
}

int main() {
    myArray a;
    a[5] = 123;
    a[8] = 321;
    int x = a[5];
    return 0;
}
```

This [prints](http://ideone.com/nsAKEO)

```
Asigning 123 to element 5
Asigning 321 to element 8
Reading element at 5
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to use a proxy class for your array and on that class define an operator[] function. Much like how std::vector does it.

You would trace when a non-const reference is produced to an array element. I think that you'd have to assume it was about to be written to. You would make the array out of your existing class so that you'd see the actual write.

The output might look like:
ref to element 32: write 1

Or however you would like it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, arrays don't support `operator=` anyway, so that is not a real a problem. You can assign to individual array elements of course, but that's already covered by your existing `operator=`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a MyArrayType that overloads the [] operator to store the values internally within an array of MyTypes